# Average Time Complexity of Searching An Array

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, average-case

Why is the average time complexity of searching an array $O(n)$? Is it because if the element does not exist, then $n$ searches must be done. If the element is at the end of the array then $n$ must also be done, so $\frac{2n}{2} = n$?

Comment: What's the significant of $2n/2$?  On average, unless you know something about the order of the elements, you'll have to look at half of them before you find the thing you're looking for.

Comment: This question is underspecified. What is the exact algorithm? What is the distribution of the elements in the array? What is the distribution of the search key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about a linear search.  If we assume that the key is equally likely to be in any of the $n$ locations in the array, then the expected location is $\frac{n+1}{2}$.  A linear search for this element would then require $O(\frac{n+1}{2}) = O(n)$ time.

Comment: @Raphael, I'm using this website as a reference: http://bigocheatsheet.com/. It does not mention which algorithm it uses to search a basic array.

Comment: @I.K. The sheet *does* differentiate between linear and binary search. There are still a couple of implementations of either concept, but all will have the same $\Theta$ runtime bounds. You need to specify which kind you mean in the question.

Comment: This explanation kind of works now (for linear search), even though I'd phrase it differently; the "expected location" intuition breaks down pretty quickly (e.g. when analysing binary search). Mathematically speaking, you do $\mathbb{E} f(x) = f(\mathbb{E} x)$ which is rarely true.